# Assign a tag to text-block if

Tags: adobe-indesign, grep

How can I assign a tag to a textblock if that textblock only if the textblock had a specific value inside (at the very beginning of the block actually.

95% of my used textblocks within my indesign document are product descriptions and if so they start with the string "**Productnumber**"
So I'd go search for "**Productnumber**" and replace the object format. But I don't want the tag to be set to the string "Productnumber" but to its mother container.

Is that possible - how?

Answer (score 1):

There is something called "Condition Text" that is found in the menu: Window > Types & Tables > Conditional Text. Is that something that would be helpful? Here is a video of someone demonstrating it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2pF8Q7Sn4U